# cloud-init userdata/metadata not loaded in ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, cloud-init, ovf

I'm using Terraform to provision virtual machines in an ESXi environment. I do this by having once manually imported the Ubuntu Focal Cloud Image as template and cloning virtual machines from it, with parameters supplied by a combination of vApp properties and extra_config:

```
vapp {
    properties = {
      "hostname" = "terraform-test"
      # user ubuntu
      "password"  = "xxx"
      "user-data" = base64encode(file("${path.module}/cloudinit/kickstart.yml"))
    }
  }
  extra_config = {
    "guestinfo.metadata"          = base64encode(file("${path.module}/cloudinit/metadata.yml"))
    "guestinfo.metadata.encoding" = "base64"
    "guestinfo.userdata"          = base64encode(file("${path.module}/cloudinit/userdata.yml"))
    "guestinfo.userdata.encoding" = "base64"
  }
```

Unfortunately, cloud-init does not apply anything from metadata/userdata.yml. The reason seems to be that while `sudo DI_LOG=stderr /usr/lib/cloud-init/ds-identify --force` yields `Found 2 datasources found=all: OVF VMware`, `cloud_id` only sees `ovf`.

The passing of the extra_config stuff works, `vmware-rpctool 'info-get guestinfo.userdata'|base64 --decode` yields the correct content - the issue therefore must be somewhere in cloud-init.

How do I tell cloud-init to force using solely the `VMware` data source?

Comment: Hello did you try to deploy ubuntu cloud image with metadata manually on vsphere?

Comment: Yes, to be precise the "focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova" image that according to its description ("VMware/Virtualbox OVA") is specifically made for VMware.